# AttributeError: module 'pytorch_lightning' has no attribute 'LightningModule'

Tags: pytorch, image-classification, pytorch-lightning

I am using google colab and pytorch lightning to train a classification model.I imported 'LightningModule' but still the error persists. This is the code.

trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)

it shows the error:
[image]

Comment: Hi Mercy, would be better if you paste your code and use text format for your error message.

Comment: could you please share a full example for reproducibility? In particular how you created the `model` passed to the `trainer.fit(...)`. Thx